# Keep user logged in Android Webview after a session

Tags: android, cookies, webview

Android Webview loads my mobile website which works on Cookies to implement  'Remember Me' feature. Issue with web view is, once user completely closes the application, it loses all cookies and it asks to credentials again.

As per google `CookieSyncManager` has been deprecated & now it syncs cookies automatically. However that's not the case with me I guess.

I tried to use:

```
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync()
```

But again as that was deprecated, it was of no use. Can any one tell me a solution which can work?
I just want the app to remember cookies (normal browser behaviour) as long as I set.